# EKS Load Balancer IP Not Found

Tags: kubernetes, service, load-balancing

I'm trying to use a load balancer to expose a service I have running on an EKS pod. My service is defined in a yaml like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mlflow-server
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mlflow-server
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mlflow-server
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 88
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
```

This is to define a service for a pod that I have mlflow server running on. When I apply this and access the external IP generated for the service, I get a `This site can’t be reached` webpage error. Is there something I'm missing with exposing my service as a load balanced service to access the mlflow ui?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have SG issues? make sure these two ports are open and then give it another try

Comment: Yes those ports are open

Answer (score 0):

For a basic Loadbalancer type service you do not need the annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb` this creates the network load balancer. Now if you need it to be an NLB then there might be following problems:

1. The nlb takes few minutes to come up when you apply the setting. If you check it just after you deploy it it will not be able to accept the traffic. Please do check if the intended network loadbalancer is up in your AWS-EC2console > Loadbalancer tab.
2. The second problem that is more likely to happen is that the NLB is can be attached with only some instance types only. To check that you can go through the following link.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#register-deregister-targets

So if you actually do not have the need of network loadbalancer remove the annotation as the nlb has an higher charge as well. But, if that is the dire requirement do check with the second option if the instances that you are using on AWS are compatible with Network LoadBalancer.